# Deleting event through the Eventbrite API

Tags: eventbrite

I've attempted to delete an event through the Eventbrite API by simply changing the event's status to 'deleted' as documented in the documentation. However, every time I do so the following error is reported:

You can't change the past, but you can recycle it using event_copy

I've tried cancelling an event and that works, but the delete functionality does not. Anyone know what this error message is specific to as it's mentioned nowhere in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the error message means, however I just send through the id and status in the array and that seems to work. I was having issues when I tried to send through an array with more than those 2 fields.